# Python3 - output __main__ file prints when running unittests (from actual program, not unittests)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, stdout, program-entry-point

How can I make that my `__main__` file prints are outputted, when I run tests? I mean prints from that file, not unittests files prints.

I have this sample structure (all files are in the same directory):

**main.py**:

```
import argparse

print('print me?')  # no output
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('name')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.name)  # no output
```

**other.py**:

```
def print_me():
    print('ran print_me')
```

**test.py**:

```
import unittest
import sh
import other


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_main(self):
        print('test_main')  # prints it.
        sh.python3('main.py', 'test123')

    def test_other(self):
        print('test_other')  # prints it.
        other.print_me()
```

And I run it with `python3 -m nose -s` or `python3 -m unittest`, but it makes no difference, prints are not outputted from `main.py`, only the ones that are defined directly on test file. Here is what I do get:

```
user@user:~/python-programs/test_main$ python3 -m nose -s
test_main
.test_other
ran print_me
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.040s

OK
```

P.S. Of course if I run `main.py` without using tests, then it prints normally (for example using python shell/interpreter and calling main.py with `sh`, just like in unittests)

Comment: This is very very odd. Why are you defining functions within that block? Why are you running your main file via a shell call?

Comment: @DanielRoseman why is it odd to you? This is test case for actual main.py usage (as if it would be called normally, not via import, and by  using arguments). And with function, yes it could be avoided. But whether there is function inside or not, it is not relevant here I guess. I can remove that function if it is distracting you from actual question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh.python3` starts new process and its output is not captured by `nose`. You can redirect the output printing the result from it:

```
print(sh.python3('main.py', 'test123'))
```

Comment: I actually tried this, but to me at first notice it looked like it only captured print inside `__main__` block.. On closer look, it does capture everything. It is exactly what I was looking for.